# Error passing Python data to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: Parse JSON in my template using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345076/django-parse-json-in-my-template-using-javascript)

I'm trying to pass a Python data structure to javascript via a GAE/Django template and following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445989/passing-python-data-to-javascript-via-django).  I'm getting an error that I can't figure out.

Here is the relevant excerpt of my Python GAE code:

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    template_values = dict(
        data = json.dumps(dict(hello = "world"))
    )
    path = os.path.join(TPATH, 'template.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Here is the relevant excerpt from the Django template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {{ data }};
</script>
```

This gives the error:

```
Invalid property id
var data = {&quot;hello&quot;: &quot;world&quot;};
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

As noted this is a duplicate and the fix is to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {{ data|safe }};
</script>
```

Comment: @Proppy, you are right.  Was searching for a wicked long time before asking my Q and didn't find that post.