# How to load bootstrapped models of backbone in Django

Tags: django, backbone.js, collections

when backbone app was loaded(for my app it means the page loaded),I need the initial collection data, and backbone docs says:

```
<script>
  var accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
  accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
  var projects = new Backbone.Collection;
  projects.reset(<%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>);
</script>
```

I don't understand this. Dose it mean I should render the page with the initial data like

```
{{collection_initial_data}}
```

I am using django on backends, so how do I translate the above code into django template,
something like

```
 <script>
  var accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
  accounts.reset({{ @accounts.to_json }});
  var projects = new Backbone.Collection;
  projects.reset({{ @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) }});
</script>
```

anyway I am really confused about getting the initial data of backbone collection.

Comment: From Backbone's doc: "*Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place.*". This simply means your data should be loaded with the page itself, not asynchronously by making a lot of AJAX call. About the django part, I don't know how, but you'll have to print the data in JSON representation.

Comment: yes that why i ask this question, " all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place" , but how???

Comment: Simply print them in the page you send the client (that's what the example's doing). Never worked with django, can't help you with that part (I'd have posted an answer if I could help you here).

Comment: I really like to know what the code above means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Backbone talks about bootstrapping, they're talking about this:

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap

In other words, they're saying you should write out the contents of your models in your Django HTML template, inside a script tag.

For instance, let's say your Django context has a variable called "foo_models", which contains the JSON representation of all of your foo models.  You'd want to edit your Django template to do something like:

```
<script>
var foo_models = new FooCollection({{foo_models}});
</script>
```

In this way you can guarantee that your data is ready on the page as it gets loaded, and your JS code can use the JS `foo_models` to access that data.

Now, your confusion seems to be with how to make the `foo_models` Python/Django variable in the first place.  I'd recommend doing this in your View logic, not in the template, as there you can use the full power of Python and its libraries to serialize the JSON.  However, if you do want to do it in your view, you can do so with a syntax that's pretty similar to what you specified; check out the second answer to this SO question:

[Django: Parse JSON in my template using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345076/django-parse-json-in-my-template-using-javascript)

Comment: hi, i did get the foo_models,but how can i get this variable in my app.js

Comment: my page structure is this:'<script src='app.js></script><script>var foo_models = new FooCollection({{foo_models}})</script>'