# How to receive context data in django template and work with it in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am trying to receive context data in django template and work with it in javascript.  Currently i am receiving the data but as a string and it looks gibberish.

my code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if search_list %}
        <!-- do something -->
    {% endif %}

    <!-- javascript code  -->

    {% block script %}
    <script >
        let data = '{{search_list}}'
        
        console.log(data);
        
    </script>
    {% endblock script %}
   

{% endblock %}
```

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import search_history


def index(request):
    search_list = search_history.objects.order_by('-query_date')[:10]
    context = {'search_list': search_list}
    return render(request, 'search_history/index.html', context)
```

If i remove the quote in the variable `search_list` in javascript it shows me error. i have used  `jsonify` and `safe` tag it doesn't work. How do i get the data as an object here?

Comment: It's a template and `{{search_list}}` will be evaluated at html generation time. Thus everything inside can be nothing but static text/string. If you want object - parse it the way you'd parse a response to AJAX request. e.g. `JSON.parse()`

Comment: There is no `receive` there is _substitution of placeholders_.

Comment: @IvanStarostin  I have tried parsing  the data to JSON but it doesn't work. in the above code the line **let data = '{{search_list}}'**  logs something like this in the console :   ```&lt;QuerySet [&lt;search_history: whats the meaning of life&gt;, &lt;search_history: how to search```

Comment: @IvanStarostin `{{search_list}}` without the quote gives this error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'`

Comment: Add your view code.

Comment: @IvanStarostin added

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345076/django-parse-json-in-my-template-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return data as JSON

```
import json

def index(request):
    search_list = search_history.objects.order_by('-query_date')[:10]
    context = {'search_list': json.dumps(search_list)}
    return render(request, 'search_history/index.html', context)
```

get it in js

```
let data = JSON.parse("{{ search_list | escapejs }}");
```

or

```
let data = {{ search_list | safe }};
```

And consider turning all this into more elegant way:

- ajax request
- json response

however making ajax request is somewhat complicated, requires manual csrf sending and so on, but you won't have to **render big constant json** values in the final html.

The view for json response and the original view would look like then:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'search_history/index.html')

def get_search_list(request):
    search_list = search_history.objects.order_by('-query_date')[:10]
    return JsonResponse({'search_list': search_list})
```