# why escaping / in javascript '<\/script>'?

Tags: javascript

I have seen everyone doing it tho i dont' get why.

```
document.write('<script src="src"><\/script>');
```

I mean using the single ' you shouldn't need to esacape chars?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: Only PHP has this stupid "no escaping in single quote strings" rule

Comment: @thief: that rule of PHP is perfectly fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Single and double quoted strings have the same escaping rules.
2. It prevents `</script>` from being parsed as an closing tag.

"`</script>` and "`<\/script>`" are the same to *JavaScript*, but only the first one is interpreted by the *HTML* parser to contain a HTML closing tag.

Answer (score 4):

`</script>` always ends a script block - no matter what (e.g. HTML comments or CDATA) you do. So it must never occur in a script block unless you actually want to end the block and the easiest way to do so is escaping forward slashes (the escaping doesn't do anything; in JavaScript unknown escape sequences just "lose" their backslash).

Comment: I don't get it. Considering javascript escapes in single quote too, aren't `</script>` and `<\/script>` the same value? Shouldn't they produce the same "error"

Comment: Yes, but it is not only longer (3 chars instead of 1 char) but also looks uglier (IMO).

Comment: @yes, yes, and I've seen that style before.

Comment: @yes, please don't edit your comment to say something entirely different.  Just post a new one.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML-parser will see the `</script>` in your string as a closing tag and close your initial `<script>`. It does not have the concept of strings.

So your piece of JavaScript will only be seen as `document.write('<script src="src">` if you dont escape it and the rest, `');` will be seen as a HTML text-node.

Also, note that you don't have to "escape" the `</script>` in a particular way. As long as you don't write it exactly like `</script>`, anything is ok. Some examples that all work:

```
document.write('<script src="src"><\/script>');
document.write('<script src="src"></scr' + 'ipt>');
document.write('<script src="src"></' + 'script>');
```