# Cannot change html script src with external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have read every single google result I could find, and this still is not working... all i'm trying to do is change a script source depending on a link that is clicked. The source files will have one or two lines returned by document.write, like so:

```
document.write(`This is content script a`);
```

So I have the following setup, an html file with two links that call the changeSrc function, which SHOULD change the source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <a id="aLink" href="#" onclick="changeSrc('a');return false;">Change to a</a/><br>
  <a id="aLink" href="#" onclick="changeSrc('b');return false;">Change to b</a/><br>
  <script id="contentScript" src="a.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The JS file:

```
function changeSrc (arg) {
    document.getElementById("contentScript").innerHTML = '';
    if (arg == "a") {
        document.getElementById("contentScript").innerHTML = '<script id="contentScript" src="a.js"></script>';
    } else if (arg == "b") { {
        document.getElementById("contentScript").innerHTML = '<script id="contentScript" src="b.js"></script>';
    }
```

}

Why is the script source not changing on the link click?!

Thank you for your time, I feel like an absolute idiot...

Comment: Not 100% sure what's going on... are you trying to write to an iframe?

Comment: do you get any errors in your browser developer console? p.s. avoid `document.write` unless it's what you really **need** to do (like working with iframes)

Comment: That first bit of code won't work unless you have a browser that supports ES6 template strings. Check your quote marks. Also, you are trying to set the `innerHTML` of a script tag which would not do what you want even if it were possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript in innerhtml not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417839/javascript-in-innerhtml-not-working)

Comment: Don't use `document.write` it *can be* a form of eval.

Comment: You cannot reuse - more than once - a script tag by modifying it's "src" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("ContentScript").src = your_script_source_here
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

1. You cannot use **duplicate ID** `aLink` `aLink`. You know what's an ID.
2. Don't use **inline JS**. Keep business logic away from the (*View*) template.
   Use a **scripting way** to assign your listeners to elements. Take a look at `addEventListener`
3. `</a/>` should be `</a>`
4. `#contentScript` is a `<script>` tag. Why are you using `innerHTML = ""` on it? Script execution is not in the scope of literal HTML.
5. You can **store the desired** *"src"* into the anchor `data-*` attribute
6. Since one can only change the `"src"` of a `<script>` tag **once**...
   you should **create a brand new `<script>` Element on the fly**:

```html
<a id="aLink" data-src="http://jsbin.com/taqadu/1/js" href="#">Change to a</a><br>
<a id="bLink" data-src="http://jsbin.com/dizavo/1/js" href="#">Change to b</a>

<script>
function id(v){return document.getElementById(v);} // Helper

function changeSrc(event){
  
  event.preventDefault(); // instead of `return false;`
  // Get already existent one
  var contentScript = id("contentScript");
  // if exists, remove it
  if(!!contentScript) contentScript.parentNode.removeChild(contentScript);
  // Create a new one
  contentScript = document.createElement("script");
  // Assign ID
  contentScript.id = "contentScript";
  // Assign "src" from the anchor's data-* attribute
  contentScript.src = this.dataset.src;
  // Finally add the newly generated `script` to body
  document.body.appendChild( contentScript );
}


id("aLink").addEventListener("click", changeSrc);
id("bLink").addEventListener("click", changeSrc);
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault